# Сборка urn и http-запрос при композиции классов

Tags: python

Всем привет!)

Предположим, есть код (не окончательный вариант):

```
from requests_toolbelt.sessions import BaseUrlSession


class B:
    urn = 'bbb'

    @classmethod
    def get(cls):
        return cls.urn


class A:
    urn = 'aaa'
    b = B


class Client:
    a = A

    def __init__(self):
        self.session = BaseUrlSession(base_url='http://example.com')
```

Необходимо, чтобы при выполнении:

```
client = Client()
response = client.a.b.get()
```

в response оказался результат выполнения self.session.get('aaa/bbb').

Здесь я вижу два пути:

1. передавать self.session сквозь классы,
2. возвращать сборный urn и в client делать запрос.

Возможно ли это сделать? И если да, то как? Я мозг сломал.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Решил при помощи модуля inspect. Вызов в методе get():

```
inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_locals
```

вернет:

```
{
    '__name__': '__main__',
    '__doc__': None,
    '__package__': None,
    '__loader__': < _frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x7f1cd8a7d5c0 > ,
    '__spec__': None,
    '__annotations__': {},
    '__builtins__': < module 'builtins'(built - in ) > ,
    '__file__': '/home/aleksandrovalbert/Work/playground/разное.py',
    '__cached__': None,
    'inspect': < module 'inspect'
    from '/usr/lib/python3.6/inspect.py' > ,
    'Dict': typing.Dict,
    'BaseUrlSession': < class 'requests_toolbelt.sessions.BaseUrlSession' > ,
    'Mark': < class '__main__.Mark' > ,
    '_B': < class '__main__._B' > ,
    '_A': < class '__main__._A' > ,
    'Client': < class '__main__.Client' > ,
    'client': < __main__.Client object at 0x7f1cd73d6e48 >
}
```

где есть все необходимое.